# How to set parameter in method like settings type

Tags: c#, .net, variables, methods, parameters

I want to create method with some kind of settings, ofcourse I could use int Para and then some ifs with if==1, if==2 etc. But i don't want this. My google skill didn't allow me to search for solution, becouse i am missing some word or something else, some phrase. I want to make this looks like:

```
void Method(int var1, int var2, Settings.type.type1){

if(type1){


}
if(type2){


}
if(type3){

}
}
```

In some methods in frameworks I saw something like this : templateType.DefoultTemplate.
I don't want strings ! I want clear parameter.
sorry for my english

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still ***really unclear*** what your goal is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032) and [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
public enum CustomType {
      Type1 = 1,
      Type2 = 2,
      Type3 = 3
 };

public void Method(CustomType t)
{
    switch (t)
    {
        case CustomType.Type1:
                  // code here
                  break;
        case CustomType.Type2:
                  // code here
                  break;
        case CustomType.Type3:

    }
}
```

Comment: Using `Type` would be _very bad_...that's a class name.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - agreed. Modified.

Comment: so fast answers :) that what i was looking for thx. I would be glad if someone will edit and correct my gramma in post and if someone has some better idea for tittle it would be nice too

Answer (score 2):

Create an enum `SettingsType` and add these values to it. Then just add switch case to do all conditional things.

So you can access it like `SettingsType.Type1` and so on.

Comment: A vague answer to a vague question.  How about an example in code?

Comment: @DonBoitnott These questions have this kind of answers :)

Comment: well he said he was missing a word, or phrase to find the answer himself in google.  I believe he was looking for 'enum'